# Hamiltonian under Canonical transformation

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian, phase-space, poisson-brackets

We know that 'Hamilton's equations' preserve in canonical transformation. But does this mean than 'Hamiltonian' itself doesn't change under canonical transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Hamiltonian can transform $H\to K = H +\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$  under a [CT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation)s that have a generator $F$ with explicit time dependence.

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics;* Chapter 9.